# how do i link an a tag to an onload modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I figured out how to make a modal window pop up as the page loads, but I was wondering how I can make it appear also after clicking on a link, so that if a first time user comes to the website, closes the onload modal window, and then wants to sign up, he can do so.

I got the code from: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/03/open-show-jquery-popup-window-on-page.html

and the website that i'm using it on is http://thewildernesswalk.businesscatalyst.com/

If you have a better solution than the tutorial i found (which would be great), I am all ears, but it seems like some of the other answers i found out there mess with the code that makes the nav stick to the top and the "back to top" button appear.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is your exact issue? What have you tried so far? Do you have any example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the code at the link you gave, you may insert the following in your HTML `<body>` in order to show the modal upon clicking hyperlink:

```html
<a href="" id="hyper">Click me!</a>
```

```js
<script>
var elem = document.getElementById('hyper');
elem.onclick = showModal;

function showModal() {
    $('.popup').show();
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you! Any way you would know how to make it fade in and out?